# Content Provider Multiple Tables Error on Update

Tags: java, android

I am using a content provider for a note taking type of app. It worked fine when I had just one table in the content provider but now that I have added another table I must have messed something up. I am able to read, write & delete in the app but when I try to click on the list item to update/edit the entry the app crashes telling me that has invalid tables.

I know the tables are not invalid because it recognizes them when I create new entries. I believe it has something to do with my content provider because it worked fine until I tried to add a second table.

Here is my code:

Content Provider

```html
package com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.contentprovider2;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

import com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.database.TodoDatabaseHelper;
import com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.database.NoteTable;
import com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.database.DeviceTable;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;

public class MyNoteContentProvider extends ContentProvider{

   // database
   private TodoDatabaseHelper database;

   // used for the UriMacher
   private static final int TODOS = 10;
   private static final int TODO_ID = 20;
   private static final int DEVICES = 30;
   private static final int DEVICE_ID = 40;

   private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.contentprovider2";

   private static final String BASE_PATH = "todos";
   private static final String DEVICE_PATH = "devices";
   
   public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_TODOS = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
       + "/" + BASE_PATH);
   public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_DEVICES = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
        + "/" + DEVICE_PATH);

   public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_TODOS = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
       + "/todos";
   public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_DEVICES = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
        + "/devices";
   
   public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
       + "/todo";
   
   //???
   public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE2 = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
        + "/device";

   private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
   static {
     sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, TODOS);
     sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", TODO_ID);
     sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, DEVICE_PATH, DEVICES);
     sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, DEVICE_PATH + "/#", DEVICE_ID);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreate() {
     database = new TodoDatabaseHelper(getContext());
     return false;
   }

   @Override
   public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
       String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

     // Uisng SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of query() method
     SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

     // check if the caller has requested a column which does not exists
     checkColumns(projection);

     // Set the table
     
     int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
     switch (uriType) {
     case TODO_ID:
       // adding the ID to the original query
       queryBuilder.appendWhere(NoteTable.COLUMN_ID + "="
           + uri.getLastPathSegment());
       break;
     case DEVICE_ID:
        // adding the ID to the original query
        queryBuilder.appendWhere(DeviceTable.COLUMN_ID + "="
            + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        break;
     case TODOS:
      queryBuilder.setTables(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO);
       break;
     case DEVICES:
       queryBuilder.setTables(DeviceTable.TABLE_DEVICE);
        break;
     default:
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
     }

     SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
         selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
     // make sure that potential listeners are getting notified
     cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

     return cursor;
   }

   @Override
   public String getType(Uri uri) {
     return null;
   }

   @Override
   public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
     int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
     SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
     int rowsDeleted = 0;
     long id = 0;
     switch (uriType) {
     case TODOS:
       id = sqlDB.insert(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO, null, values);
       break;
     case DEVICES:
    id = sqlDB.insert(DeviceTable.TABLE_DEVICE, null, values);
    break;
     default:
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
     }
     getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
     return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH + "/" + id);
     
 
   }

   //Deleted Rows
   
   @Override
   public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
     int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
     SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
     int rowsDeleted = 0;
     switch (uriType) {
     case TODOS:
       rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO, selection,
           selectionArgs);
       break;
     case TODO_ID:
       String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
       if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
         rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO,
             NoteTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, 
             null);
       } else {
         rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO,
             NoteTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id 
             + " and " + selection,
             selectionArgs);
       }
       break;
     case DEVICES:
        rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(DeviceTable.TABLE_DEVICE, selection,
            selectionArgs);
        break;
      case DEVICE_ID:
        String id2 = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
          rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(DeviceTable.TABLE_DEVICE,
              NoteTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id2, 
              null);
        } else {
          rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO,
              NoteTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id2 
              + " and " + selection,
              selectionArgs);
        }
        break;
     default:
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
     }
     getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
     return rowsDeleted;
   }

   
   //Update Rows
   @Override
   public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
       String[] selectionArgs) {

     int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
     SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
     int rowsUpdated = 0;
     switch (uriType) {
     case TODOS:
       rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO, 
           values, 
           selection,
           selectionArgs);
       break;
     case TODO_ID:
       String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
       if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
         rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO, 
             values,
             NoteTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, 
             null);
       } else {
         rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO, 
             values,
             NoteTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id 
             + " and " 
             + selection,
             selectionArgs);
       }
       break;
     case DEVICES:
        rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(DeviceTable.TABLE_DEVICE, 
            values, 
            selection,
            selectionArgs);
        break;
      case DEVICE_ID:
        String id2 = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
          rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(DeviceTable.TABLE_DEVICE, 
              values,
              DeviceTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id2, 
              null);
        } else {
          rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(DeviceTable.TABLE_DEVICE, 
              values,
              DeviceTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id2 
              + " and " 
              + selection,
              selectionArgs);
        }
        break;
     default:
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
     }
     getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
     return rowsUpdated;
   }

   private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {
     String[] available = { NoteTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY,
         NoteTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, NoteTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, NoteTable.COLUMN_EMAIL, NoteTable.COLUMN_RENTALDATES, 
         NoteTable.COLUMN_ENDDATES, NoteTable.COLUMN_TIME, NoteTable.COLUMN_LOCATION, NoteTable.COLUMN_NOTES,
         NoteTable.COLUMN_ID, DeviceTable.COLUMN_ID, DeviceTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY, DeviceTable.COLUMN_NAME, DeviceTable.COLUMN_TYPE };
     if (projection != null) {
       HashSet<String> requestedColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(projection));
       HashSet<String> availableColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(available));
       // check if all columns which are requested are available
       if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
       }
     }
   }
}
```

CustomerEdit.java

```html
package com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety;
import com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.contentprovider2.MyNoteContentProvider;
import com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.database.NoteTable;

import android.app.Activity;
import com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.database.R;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

/*
 * TodoDetailActivity allows to enter a new todo item 
 * or to change an existing
 */
public class CustomerEdit extends Activity {
  private Spinner mCategory;
  private EditText mTitleText;
  private EditText mBodyText;
  private EditText mEmailAddress;
  private EditText mRentalDates;
  private EditText mEndDate;
  private EditText mTime;
  private EditText mLocationAddress;
  private EditText mNoteEditText;

  private Uri todoUri;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.customer_edit);

    mCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.category);
    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todo_edit_summary);
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
    mEmailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
    mRentalDates = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rentalDates);
    mEndDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endDate);
    mTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
    mLocationAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationAddress);
    mNoteEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);
    
    Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.todo_edit_button);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    // check from the saved Instance
    todoUri = (bundle == null) ? null : (Uri) bundle
        .getParcelable(MyNoteContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

    // Or passed from the other activity
    if (extras != null) {
      todoUri = extras
          .getParcelable(MyNoteContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

      fillData(todoUri);
    }

    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mTitleText.getText().toString())) {
          makeToast();
        } else {
          setResult(RESULT_OK);
          finish();
        }
      }

    });
  }

  private void fillData(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { NoteTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY,
        NoteTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, NoteTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY, NoteTable.COLUMN_EMAIL, NoteTable.COLUMN_RENTALDATES, 
        NoteTable.COLUMN_ENDDATES, NoteTable.COLUMN_TIME, NoteTable.COLUMN_LOCATION, NoteTable.COLUMN_NOTES };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
        null);
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      String category = cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NoteTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY));

      for (int i = 0; i < mCategory.getCount(); i++) {

        String s = (String) mCategory.getItemAtPosition(i);
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(category)) {
          mCategory.setSelection(i);
        }
      }

      mTitleText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NoteTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY)));
      mBodyText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NoteTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));
      mEmailAddress.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
           .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NoteTable.COLUMN_EMAIL)));
      mRentalDates.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
           .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NoteTable.COLUMN_RENTALDATES)));
      mEndDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
           .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NoteTable.COLUMN_ENDDATES)));
      mTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
           .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NoteTable.COLUMN_TIME)));
      mLocationAddress.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
           .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NoteTable.COLUMN_LOCATION)));
      mNoteEditText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
           .getColumnIndexOrThrow(NoteTable.COLUMN_NOTES)));
     

      // always close the cursor
      cursor.close();
    }
  }

  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putParcelable(MyNoteContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, todoUri);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
  }

  private void saveState() {
    String category = (String) mCategory.getSelectedItem();
    String summary = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String description = mBodyText.getText().toString();
    String email = mEmailAddress.getText().toString();
    String rentaldates = mRentalDates.getText().toString();
    String enddate = mEndDate.getText().toString();
    String time = mTime.getText().toString();
    String location = mLocationAddress.getText().toString();
    String notes = mNoteEditText.getText().toString();


    // only save if either summary or description
    // is available

    if (description.length() == 0 && summary.length() == 0) {
      return;
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NoteTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
    values.put(NoteTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, summary);
    values.put(NoteTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(NoteTable.COLUMN_EMAIL, email);
    values.put(NoteTable.COLUMN_RENTALDATES, rentaldates);
    values.put(NoteTable.COLUMN_ENDDATES, enddate);
    values.put(NoteTable.COLUMN_TIME, time);
    values.put(NoteTable.COLUMN_LOCATION, location);
    values.put(NoteTable.COLUMN_NOTES, notes);
   

    if (todoUri == null) {
      // New todo
      todoUri = getContentResolver().insert(MyNoteContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_TODOS, values);
    } else {
      // Update todo
      getContentResolver().update(todoUri, values, null, null);
    }
  }

  private void makeToast() {
    Toast.makeText(CustomerEdit.this, "Please maintain a summary",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

NoteTable.java

```html
package com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.database;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class NoteTable {

  // Database table
   public static final String TABLE_TODO = "todo";
   public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
   public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
   public static final String COLUMN_SUMMARY = "summary";
   public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
   public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
   public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
   public static final String COLUMN_RENTALDATES = "rentaldates";
   public static final String COLUMN_ENDDATES = "enddates";
   public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";
   public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION = "location";
   public static final String COLUMN_NOTES = "notes";
 
 

   // Database creation SQL statement
   private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " 
       + TABLE_TODO
       + "(" 
       + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
       + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, " 
       + COLUMN_SUMMARY + " text not null," 
       + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text not null," 
       + COLUMN_EMAIL + " text not null," 
    + COLUMN_RENTALDATES + " text not null,"
    + COLUMN_ENDDATES + " text not null,"
    + COLUMN_TIME + " text not null,"
    + COLUMN_LOCATION + " text not null,"
    + COLUMN_NOTES + " text not null"
       + ");";

   public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
     database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
   }

   public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
       int newVersion) {
     Log.w(NoteTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
         + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
         + ", which will destroy all old data");
     database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODO);
     onCreate(database);
   }
 
}
```

DeviceTable.java

```html
package com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.database;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class DeviceTable {

  // Database table
   public static final String TABLE_DEVICE = "device";
   public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
   public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
   public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
   public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
 
 
 

   // Database creation SQL statement
   private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " 
       + TABLE_DEVICE
       + "(" 
       + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
       + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, " 
       + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null," 
       + COLUMN_TYPE + " text not null" 
       
       + ");";

   public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
     database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
   }

   public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
       int newVersion) {
     Log.w(DeviceTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
         + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
         + ", which will destroy all old data");
     database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DEVICE);
     onCreate(database);
   }
 
}
```

And my database helper

```html
package com.cossioinsurance.rentalsafety.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class TodoDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todotable.db";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 
 
 
 

   public TodoDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   // Method is called during creation of the database
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
     NoteTable.onCreate(database);
     DeviceTable.onCreate(database);
    
   }

   // Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
   // e.g. if you increase the database version
   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
       int newVersion) {
     NoteTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    DeviceTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
     
   }

}
```

If any one can see anything I might be missing please let me know, I am new to programming and I am really wracking my brain over this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It seems that my query set tables was not set up quite right. I had to add
queryBuilder.setTables(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO); to all of the cases in the query. I had previously not added that statement to the _ID cases.

```java
 @Override
      public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
          String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        // Uisng SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of query() method
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        // check if the caller has requested a column which does not exists
        checkColumns(projection);

        // Set the table


        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (uriType) {
        case TODOS:
            queryBuilder.setTables(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO);
          break;
        case TODO_ID:
            queryBuilder.setTables(NoteTable.TABLE_TODO);
          // adding the ID to the original query
          queryBuilder.appendWhere(NoteTable.COLUMN_ID + "="
              + uri.getLastPathSegment());
          break;
        case DEVICES:
            queryBuilder.setTables(DeviceTable.TABLE_DEVICE);
          break;
        case DEVICE_ID:
            queryBuilder.setTables(DeviceTable.TABLE_DEVICE);
          // adding the ID to the original query
          queryBuilder.appendWhere(DeviceTable.COLUMN_ID + "="
              + uri.getLastPathSegment());
          break;
        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
            selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        // make sure that potential listeners are getting notified
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        return cursor;
      }
```